# using groovy-postbuild-plugin in my Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to use the  groovy-postbuild-plugin  in my Jenkins pipeline,
I can get it to work for displaying plain text,
But I can't use it with parameters.

So this is working:

```
stage('postbuild disply service built') {
    currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createShortText("test"));
}
```

[image]

But this one doesn't:

```
stage('postbuild disply service built') {
    manager.addShortText("${manager.build.buildVariables.get('REPO_NAME')}");
}
```

This  is the error I get:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun buildVariables
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that I could use the "creatrShortText" class and it will take what is inside the double quotes as a parameter.
Something like that:

```
stage('postbuild display service and branch') {
    currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createShortText("${REPO_NAME}"));
    manager.addShortText("${SCM_BRANCH}", "black", "white", "1px", "green");
}
```

[image]