# How to run a Groovy postbuild script from Jenkinsfile(pipeline)?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a groovy postbuild script which I want to now integrate with in a Jenkinsfile but I can't get it to work. Here si a stage I have come up with but it doesn't do anything:

```
    stage('Categorize Build'){

            log_parser = load "postbuild.groovy"
            log_parser.logParser()

    }
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661032/using-groovy-postbuild-plugin-in-my-jenkins-pipeline) but I don't really see how I can call a script.

Comment: So maybe the `postbuild.groovy` does nothing?

Comment: well it has a bunch of details and it works fine in freestyle job. There are api;s like manager.<> and it is specific to Groovy postbuild plugin.